# shuffle in randomize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, shuffle

I recently had trouble of making:

1. i created an randomization_array which i import all of my 8
   images....
2. i created an data plist of 8 images(NSDictionary)
3. then,

   ```
   NSMutableArray *randomization_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   [randomization_array addObjectsFromArray:array];
   [randomization_array addObjectsFromArray:array];   

   NSMutableArray *shuffled_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:randomization_array];

   for(int x=0;x<[randomization_array count]/2;x++)
   {
       int random = arc4random_uniform([randomization_array count] / 2 );

       int destination = random *2;

       NSDictionary *origin_dict = [randomization_array objectAtIndex:x];
       NSDictionary *destionation_dict= [randomization_array objectAtIndex:destination];

       [shuffled_array insertObject:origin_dict atIndex:destination];
       [shuffled_array insertObject:destionation_dict atIndex:x];            
   }
   ```
4. i make it 2 set of the random images....
5. my question,how should i make only two set of images.... every time
   i shuffle the images should come in pair 8+8=16....looking forward
   to the codes frens

Answer (score 2):

hello i have used for random  shuffle in randomize and grid view usig the AQGRIDVIEW pls refer this and implement using this .below is link download code and use this

https://github.com/sync/AQGridView

Happy coding :)